# Reusing classes of a second EAR file

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ear, reusability

Using JBoss, I created two separate EAR files:

EAR1 ----->

1. web

   - MemberController.java
   - VenueController.java
2. ejb

   - Member.java
   - Venue.java

EAR2 ----->

1. web

   - MemberController.java
2. ejb

   - Member.java

Now, for EAR2, I would like to extend Venue.java and VenueController.java by importing them from EAR1 without having to copy all the code.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about JBoss AS 7 ? in JBoss AS 7 applications that are packaged as top-level archives (such as WAR, JAR, and SAR) are assigned the following module name:

deployment.[archive name]

In applications that contain nested modules (such as the EAR archive), every single archive will be assigned a module name using this classification:

deployment.[ear archive name].[sub deployment archive name] 
So, for example the Web application, if contained in the archive Ear1.ear, will be deployed with the name:

deployment.Ear1.ear.WebExample1.war

You can add a dependency in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF of the archive which references the Web application deployed separately:

**Dependencies: deployment.Ear1.ear.WebExample1.war**

As an alternative, you can add a **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** needs to be placed within the META-INF folder of the EAR1:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<sub-deployment name="WebExample2.war">
   <dependencies>
     <module name="deployment.Ear1.ear.WebExample1.war" />
    </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I did, but I get a classloader error every time I try it.